# Need XSLT selector for xhtml:link

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following XML. I have added the `xhtml:link` myself.

```
<url>
    <loc>https://sitename/choix-entrepreneur/12-questions-a-poser-a-votre-entrepreneur/</loc>
    <lastmod>2017-09-01T21:06:07+05:00</lastmod>
    <image:image>
        <image:loc>https://sitename/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/questions-aux-entrepreneurs-non-verifies-par-reno-assistance-1.jpg</image:loc>
        <image:title><!--[CDATA[questions-aux-entrepreneurs-non-verifies-par-reno-assistance]]--></image:title>
        <image:caption><!--[CDATA[questions-aux-entrepreneurs-non-verifies-par-reno-assistance]]--></image:caption>
    </image:image>
    <image:image>
        <image:loc>http://sitename/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/360verification_fr.png</image:loc>
        <image:caption><!--[CDATA[Rapport de vérification à 360° dans l'écran d'un ordinateur]]--></image:caption>
    </image:image>
    <image:image>
        <image:loc>http://sitename/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/calendrier-entrepreneur.jpg</image:loc>
        <image:caption><!--[CDATA[Agenda d'un entrepreneur en construction ou rénovation]]--></image:caption>
    </image:image>
    <image:image>
        <image:loc>http://sitename/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/famille-deplace-sofa-avant-renovations.jpg</image:loc>
        <image:caption><!--[CDATA[Couple déménageant un sofa]]--></image:caption>
    </image:image>
    <image:image>
        <image:loc>http://sitename/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/homme-regardant-telephone.jpg</image:loc>
        <image:caption><!--[CDATA[Homme regardant son téléphone intelligent]]--></image:caption>
    </image:image>
    <image:image>
        <image:loc>http://sitename/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/conteneur-a-dechet-construction-blogue.jpg</image:loc>
        <image:caption><!--[CDATA[Conteneur à déchet de construction]]--></image:caption>
    </image:image>
        <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="https://sitename/en/?p=102151"></xhtml:link>
```

Now for this XML we are processing this in XSLT. But I am unable to process the `xhtml:link` in HTML. I don't know how do i select it. I have the following code to do this. Help would be much appreciated..

```
<td>
  <xsl:variable name="hrefLANG">
    <xsl:value-of select="sitemap:[@rel='alternate']/@href"/>
  </xsl:variable>
  <a href="{$hrefLANG}">
    <xsl:value-of select="sitemap:[@rel='alternate']/@href"/>
  </a>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches:

1. You can define the XHTML namespace `http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml` in your 
   XSLT on your `<xsl:stylesheet ...` element with

   ```
   xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   ```

   and then access it with

   ```
   <xsl:variable name="hrefLANG">
       <xsl:value-of select="//xhtml:link[@rel='alternate']/@href"/>
   </xsl:variable>
   <xsl:element name="a">
       <xsl:attribute name="href">
           <xsl:value-of select="$hrefLANG"/>
       </xsl:attribute>
   </xsl:element>
   ```

   The element is constructed with `xsl:element` to get rid of the namespace in the output
2. You can ignore the namespace - which is less precise, but may also work

   ```
   <xsl:variable name="hrefLANG">
       <xsl:value-of select="//*[local-name()='link'][@rel='alternate']/@href"/>
   </xsl:variable>
   <xsl:element name="a">
       <xsl:attribute name="href">
           <xsl:value-of select="$hrefLANG"/>
       </xsl:attribute>
   </xsl:element>
   ```

The output in both cases is

```
<a href="https://sitename.com/en/?p=102151"/>
```

Comment: I see two steps in your answer. First is to add `xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"` I did that and the XML was working. As soon as i add the XSLT the sitemap stops working this is also the same with the 2nd approach. So there is something wrong in fetching the url i guess. Let me share a sample which is working maybe this helps: `<xsl:variable name="itemURL">
         <xsl:value-of select="sitemap:loc"/>
        </xsl:variable>`

Comment: What do you mean by `As soon as i add the XSLT the sitemap stops working`? Where did you add the XSLT code? And how do you call it? And from where?

Comment: This is a public WordPress plugin by the name Yoast SEO. The xslt file is `https://github.com/Yoast/wordpress-seo/blob/trunk/css/main-sitemap.xsl`. The code you gave me I added after the link 129. It means that I see a blank white screen with nothing on it. When i remove the code and refresh the page I see the sitemap again